# How to auto feed blogger to wordpress website as wp-posts?

Tags: wordpress, blogger

Hi I'm Newbie to blogger, I googled a lot but there is no result coming to autofeed blogger to Wordpress. I want to display and post blogger posts to wordpress post. Please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Blogger service, sometimes referred to as Blogspot, does not offer automatic publishing using RSS feeds. You can, however, use a WordPress plug-in to automatically feed your WordPress blog posts into your Blogger account. This is useful if you want the same content published on Blogger as on your WordPress blog. The process does not work with WordPress blogs hosted on WordPress.com; it only works on self-hosted WordPress blogs.

1. Sign in to your WordPress admin panel. Click on "Add New" in the "Plugins" sidebar column.
2. Type "Network Publisher" and then hit "Search." Click on "Install" and then click "Activate."
3. Click on "Get API Key." This directs you to LinksAlpha. Create an account and sign in or connect with your Google account.
4. Click on "Blogger" and then click on "Add Blogger Account." Enter your Blogspot URL and then enter your user name and password. Click "Save."
5. Highlight the API key with your cursor. Right-click and select "Copy." Close the browser tab and return to the WordPress administration panel.
6. Click on "Network Publisher." Paste your API key into the "API Key" box. Click "Add API Key." Check the box next to "Enable Publishing" and then click "Update." Your WordPress blog posts will now be synchronized with your Blogger account.